# Is there an additional option to display hidden command on the terminal?

Tags: debian, command-line, security, web

Copy and pasting from a website to the terminal is very harmful , there are an example [here](http://www.h-online.com/security/services/Copy-Paste-Tricks-1842855.html)

You past the following line :`ls /some/thing/much/too/long/to/type/` , by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> the following command will be executed without confirmation:

```
ls /dev/null; clear; echo -n "Hello ";whoami|tr -d '\n';echo -e '!\nGotcha!!!\nThis is the first line of your /etc/passwd: ';head -n1 /etc/passwd
ls /some/thing/much/too/long/to/type/
```

The text editor like `vim` , `nano`... can display easily the hidden command.
Using a **multi user operating system** , is that possible to find an additional **option** , **package** or configuration file to display the hidden command on the terminal before to be executed ?

Comment: Related: [How can I protect myself from this kind of clipboard abuse?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/39118)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most portable way to see "hidden commands" is probably using

```
cat -v
```

For instance, I might run "cat -v" and paste into that terminal to see the nonprinting characters.

Further reading:

- [How can I see what my keyboard sends?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#visible_keys) (ncurses FAQ)

Comment: Except that if the clipboard contains `^Devil command^M` and your terminal like konsole doesn't strip that `^D`, that won't help. You'd rather want to use something like `xclip -sel c -o | LC_ALL=C sed -n l` (which would also avoid problem with Unicode characters that look like some ASCII ones)